# How to generate roll number such that two person with same surname cannot be in the same order

Tags: php, html

I have a candidate Registration table with columns:

```
name, father_name, subject, dob, candidate_roll_no
```

I want to generate a roll number such that no two person with same surname are next to each other.

Comment: And your attempt was?

Comment: Suppose your table contains only two entries. And every candidate has the name "Luke Skywalker". Then it's impossible since every candidate has the same surname.

Comment: their is little possibility that two person will have same name

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Sort the table according to the surname - ascending or descending doesn't matter - and read it into an array.
2. Shuffle the lower half of the array and the upper half of the array.
3. If you have an even amount of elements in your array, make the last entry the new first one
4. The index of each element will be the roll number of the candidate

It would look like this:

suppose you have 10 elements in your array:
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

Then after the shuffle it would look like this:
(1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9, 10)

Because you have an even amount of entries, you move the last one:
(10, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9)

---

suppose you have 9 elements in your array:
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

Then after the shuffle it would look like this:
(1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7, 4, 8, 5, 9)

Because thats an odd amount of elements - you are done.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion i will try this method